# Quantlib specify contract duration instead of dates

Tags: options, quantlib, american, date

I use the following code in Python to price American put/call options. It's simple code since I'm new to using Quantlib. I would like to specify the contract duration (i.e. `T=1`, `T=2`, etc.) instead of specifying the calculation and maturity dates. Is it possible to do this? If so, how can I modify the code below to achieve this?

```
import QuantLib as ql

def OptionPrices(T, r, sigma, K, S0, TimeSteps):
    maturity_date = ql.Date(31, 12, 2020)
    calculation_date = ql.Date(1, 1, 2020)
    ql.Settings.instance().evaluationDate = calculation_date    

    payoff = ql.PlainVanillaPayoff(ql.Option.Call, K)

    am_exercise = ql.AmericanExercise(calculation_date, maturity_date)
    american_option = ql.VanillaOption(payoff, am_exercise)

    spot_handle = ql.QuoteHandle(ql.SimpleQuote(S0))
    flat_ts = ql.YieldTermStructureHandle(ql.FlatForward(calculation_date, r, ql.Actual365Fixed()))
    dividend_yield = ql.YieldTermStructureHandle(ql.FlatForward(calculation_date, 0, ql.Actual365Fixed()))
    flat_vol_ts = ql.BlackVolTermStructureHandle(ql.BlackConstantVol(calculation_date, ql.UnitedStates(), sigma, ql.Actual365Fixed()))
    bsm_process = ql.BlackScholesMertonProcess(spot_handle, dividend_yield, flat_ts, flat_vol_ts)

    binomial_engine = ql.BinomialVanillaEngine(bsm_process, "crr", TimeSteps)
    american_option.setPricingEngine(binomial_engine)

    OptionPrices.AmCallPrices = [binomial_price(american_option, bsm_process, step) for step in range(2, TimeSteps+1, 1)]
    OptionPrices.AmCallPrice = american_option.NPV()


    payoff = ql.PlainVanillaPayoff(ql.Option.Put, K)

    american_option = ql.VanillaOption(payoff, am_exercise)

    OptionPrices.AmPutPrices = [binomial_price(american_option, bsm_process, step) for step in range(2, TimeSteps+1, 1)]
    OptionPrices.AmPutPrice = american_option.NPV()

def binomial_price(option, bsm_process, steps):
    binomial_engine = ql.BinomialVanillaEngine(bsm_process, "crr", steps)
    option.setPricingEngine(binomial_engine)
    return option.NPV()

OptionPrices(1, 0.06, 0.15, 100, 90, 200)
print(OptionPrices.AmPutPrice)
```

I would appreciate any help. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about just defining the maturity date as todays date (or any other start date) ajusted by a period of `T x 365` days? Here is an example:

```
T = 0.5
today = ql.Date().todaysDate()
maturity = today + ql.Period(f"{int(T*365)}d")
```

Comment: Hello David. Thank you, it works perfectly. I appreciate your help.

Comment: `ql.Period(int(T*365), ql.Days)` has the same effect and might be a bit less cryptic.